# Border between Share/Edit/Close/Flag links gone

Tags: discussion, design

There have been a bunch of discussion topics about the recent SO design change, but one question I haven't seen asked was about a very small detail, the vertical separator between the share/edit/close/flag links that appear below the tags for a question.

It used to look similar to (image from Google images, hence 'link' instead of 'share'):

[image]

Now it looks like (as it actually appears today):

[image]

I wasn't sure if I had imagined the separator, however after a quick Google image search I realized that I wasn't dreaming it up. Any chance of making a very simple, small CSS change and bringing the vertical separators back?

Comment: The lack of a separator is actually consistent with every SE theme ever made after the trilogy. I don't think any other sites have them.

Comment: @animuson - The thing is, the bars already exist in the markup (even on the other sites).

Comment: @TravisJ Well, all sites use the same code, and Super User and Server Fault still have the separators. I'm sure if they ever get a similar redesign as Stack Overflow did, they'll probably get completely removed from the code.

Comment: @animuson - I wonder what the need to keep extra content in the code is when the exchanges have such epic version control.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix I think (sorry to harp, but what is with all of the duplication in the css files? honestly.... )

The definition for this already exists. Here is the css definition for those bars

```
.lsep {
 margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
 color: #ccc;
 color: #1b4072;
 font-size: 1px;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

**and also** the overriding margin definition

```
.post-menu .lsep {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

And here is the bar elements (span) currently in the markup

[image]

All of this could have simply been done by removing the span elements so I am baffled. Anyway, to get the bar back, just remove the *entire* `.post-menu .lsep` definition, and change the `.lsep` definition to

```
.lsep {
 margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
 color: #ccc;
}
```

And now you get

[image]